# AngularJS: On click section then Apply values to contained inputs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom

I am learning Angular.JS. I am also trying to "drop the crutch of Jquery", and implement this in "The Angular Way".

I have ng-repeat creating DOM elements. There are several div sections and within them input items. I would like to be able to click the section text and have angular apply normal values to contained input elements. My mind immediately goes to JQuery: sending the element as an argument, then loop children inputs and update them. I suspect his is an example of bad Angular. Should I be finding the section in the data object, looping children and updating values there?

```js
var data = [
    {
        "id": "exam1",
        "text": "exam1",
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": "section1",
                "text": "section1",
                "lines": [
                    {
                        "line": [
                            {
                                "pretext": "preone:",
                                "normal": "normal for one",
                            },
                            {

                                "pretext": "pretwo:",
                                "normal": "normal for two",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "section2",
                "text": "section2",
                "lines": [
                    {
                        "line": [
                            {
                                "pretext": "prethree:",
                                "normal": "normal for three"
                            },
                            {
                                "pretext": "prefour:",
                                "normal": "normal for four"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
]
  
angular.module('examsApp', [])

.controller('ExamsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var examsList = this;
        examsList.exams = data;
  
  $scope.fillNorms = function() {
    // loop inputs in section?
     // bullet.value = bullet.normal?
     alert("fill bullet.normal")
}
  
 }])
```

```css
.ie-section-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ie-section-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-App="examsApp">
 <div id="exams" class="ie-exam" ng-controller="ExamsController as examsList">
        <div id="{{exam.id}}" class="ie-exam" ng-repeat="exam in examsList.exams">
            {{exam.text}}
            <div id="{{section.id}}" ng-click="fillNorms()" class="ie-section-wrapper" ng-repeat="section in exam.sections">
                <span examsection="{{section.id}}" class="ie-section-box">{{section.text}}
                </span>
                <span class="ie-lines-wrapper">
                    <span class="ie-line" ng-repeat="lines in section.lines">
                        <span class="ie-bullet" ng-repeat="bullet in lines.line">
                            <span class="ie-pretext">{{bullet.pretext}}</span>
                            <span class="ie-inputwrapper">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="bullet.value" class="ie-input" />
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess most people struggling to understand what you want... First you can make 'bad Angular'' plunk - then it is supereasy to tell you what to change... But it seems like you need just ng-click="fillNorms(exam)"  and then do whatever you want with this object in controller.

Comment: Click on section:

https://plnkr.co/edit/biuXL5p91Su3jSthuwW4?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Demo

Here's the plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/M1jiWiZtTWWGyezmNJMG?p=preview

I hope this is what you wanted

## Explaination

First of all let's pass the `section` to be filled to the `fillNorms` function :

```
<div id="{{section.id}}" ng-click="fillNorms(section)" ... >
```

Now let's make a javascript equivalent of `ng-repeat`s so that we can access the input value (which apparently is named bullet) in the `fillNorms` function:

```
... 
ng-repeat="lines in section.lines"
    ...
    ng-repeat="bullet in lines.line"
    ...
...
```

becomes

```
angular.forEach(section.lines, function(lines){
    angular.forEach(lines.line, function(bullet){
        ...
    })
})
```

And finally let's change the value of input whose `ng-model` is `bullet.value`

```
bullet.value = bullet.normal
```

The final `fillNorms` function now looks like this :

```
$scope.fillNorms = function(section) {
    angular.forEach(section.lines, function(lines){
        angular.forEach(lines.line, function(bullet){
            bullet.value = bullet.normal;
        })
    })
}
```

And the only unwanted thing is that when `input` is clicked to type some other value by the user, the `section`'s click event is also being triggered (because input is a child of section)
To overcome this we'll use the `event.stopPropagation()` method

```
<input ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ...>
```

Now, when the input is clicked `fillNorms` function is not called because we are stopping the click event from propagating to the parent elements

Comment: Would have never through of doing the equivalent of ng-repeat in the controller. Makes sense through. Much appreciated.

Comment: @cycle4passion Happy to help :) Btw, this was my first SO answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below link: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/9FWIZYlbqivLpGdtUXNT?p=preview

Following are the changes:

```
<div id="{{section.id}}" ng-click="section.isClick=true"...>
   ...
   <input type="text" ng-model="(section.isClick) ? bullet.normal: ''" ... />
   ...
</div>
```

Here, I am using isClick boolean property for each section, to determine section is clicked.

Comment: looks good until you go to edit after a click, then cannot be changed

Comment: What is your requirement, can you elloborate

Comment: I would like it to work as current, but still be able to edit the input element after the section has been clicked.

Comment: I updated the Plunker as per my understanding. Any deviation kindly let me know. https://plnkr.co/edit/9FWIZYlbqivLpGdtUXNT?p=preview

Comment: Does not work as desired. Current version fills normal on any keypress in input. Also clicking section fills as desired, but input cannot be manually edited therafter.